# Show specific number of items for each row dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to render elements from an array using an ngFor loop. The array can be of different sizes.

I want that always 5 elements of an array make one row.

For example, if my array were of size seven:

```
Element Element Element Element Element
Element Element
```

Or of size 15:

```
Element Element Element Element Element
Element Element Element Element Element
Element Element Element Element Element
```

etc.

What kind of HTML elements is not relevant at first. I just want to understand how this could be implemented with ngFor in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `grid`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
</div>
```

Or, if you want, you can achieve it using a `flex` layout:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex > div {
  border: 1px solid;
   flex: 0 1 calc(20% - 16px);
  padding: 0px 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Foo</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Bar</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
</div>
```

*Sidenote* : using the `flex` approach you would have a much easier life when (and if) dealing with responsiveness. IE: you could add a `flex-wrap: wrap` and a `min-width` to the divs and let flex handle it.

On the other hand, if using the `grid` approach, you could simply add some `@media` and change how `grid-template-columns` render the items.

That's up to you, but anyway both ways are valid.